# Function to print 4x4 emote grid in a discord chat

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

New python-enthusiast here.

I am currently making a discord bot that responds with 16 pictures in a 4x4-grid when a specific user types in the chat:

```
XXXX

XXXX

XXXX

XXXX
```

This is my current code:

````
import discord
from secrets import TOKEN
from emotes import *

# user IDs
bonvang_ID = "417010736988946444"
djursing_ID = "124806046568022016"
jonathan_ID = "151788707760832512"
alex_ID = "151745760935936001"
snuffles_ID = "221360712222507009"

# bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
client = discord.Client()

# prints message in terminal when bot is ready
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {client.user}")


# @client.event
# async def on_member_join(member):
#     await message.channel.send(f"""Welcome to the server {member}!\n
#         I'm just a simple bot made by Mr.Nofox.\n
#         If you want to know more about the commands, ask him or try your luck with the others! :)""")


def member_amount():
    # create a variable that contains all the servers
    active_servers = client.servers
    # create a variable to store amount of members per server
    sum = 0
    # loop through the servers, get all members and add them up, this includes bots
    for s in active_servers:
        sum += len(s.members)
    return sum


def picture_grid():
    return (f"{pic01} {pic02} {pic03} {pic04}\n{pic05} {pic06} {pic07} {pic08}\n{pic09} {pic10} {pic11} {pic12}\n{pic13} {pic14} {pic15} {pic16}\n)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # print(f"{message.channel}: {message.author}: \"{message.content}\"")
    guild = client.get_all_members()

    if "!count()" == message.content:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, f"```py\nTotal members: {member_amount()}```")

    elif "!report()" == message.content:
        online = 0
        idle = 0
        offline = 0

        for member in guild:
            if str(member.status) == "online":
                online += 1
            if str(member.status) == "offline":
                offline += 1
            if str(member.status) == "idle" or str(member.status) == "dnd":
                idle += 1

        await client.send_message(message.channel, f"```Online: {online}\nIdle/busy.dnd: {idle}\nOffline: {offline}```")


    #TODO: Make a neat function for the pictures in message that responds with 4x4 image in chat when a given user types
    if (message.author.id == alex_ID or message.author.id == snuffles_ID):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "DET ER MIN SØN!")
        await client.send_message(message.channel, picture_grid())


# add bot-token found on website
client.run(TOKEN)
````

All the emotes are in a file called "emotes.py" which I import.
Each emote is a string-code, example:
`pic01 = '<:1_:543049824644235265>'`

The line I am using to get this to work atm. is:

```
await client.send_message(message.channel, f"{pic01} {pic02} {pic03} {pic04}\n{pic05} {pic06} {pic07} {pic08}\n{pic09} {pic10} {pic11} {pic12}\n{pic13} {pic14} {pic15} {pic16}\n")
```

This is awful coding practice and therefore I want to make a function that returns:

```
f"{pic01} {pic02} {pic03} {pic04}\n{pic05} {pic06} {pic07} {pic08}\n{pic09} {pic10} {pic11} {pic12}\n{pic13} {pic14} {pic15} {pic16}\n"
```

My initial thought was something like:

```
def picture_grid():  
    return (f"{pic01} {pic02} {pic03} {pic04}\n{pic05} {pic06} {pic07} {pic08}\n{pic09} {pic10} {pic11} {pic12}\n{pic13} {pic14} {pic15} {pic16}\n")
```

This does the trick and converts the first code to:

```
await client.send_message(message.channel, picture_grid())
```

But merely moves the bad code to another place.. I am currently stuck by what should be a simple task.

Any ideas?

Comment: The message you're sending has the exact same text every time.  Why not just store that as a text file and then `f.read()` that file to form the body of your message?

Comment: Worked like a charm @PatrickHaugh, thank you so much. :)